# adding special characters to folder names

Tags: bash

I have a very long list of folders with the following naming convention

```
ABS1789_2563-01
ABS1789_2563-02
ABS1789_2563-02

.
.
.
```

How can I add " - " between ABS and 1789 then replace "_" by "-" between 1789 and 2563 using bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IFS="\n"                        # Handle files with spaces in the names
for file in ABS*; do
    newfile="${file/ABS/ABS-}"  # Add the hyphen following ABS
    newfile="${newfile/_/-}"    # Change the underscore to a hyphen
    mv "$file" "$newfile"       # Make the change
done
```

In light of Tony's comments below, a more general use version could be as follows:

```
IFS="\n"                          # Handle files with spaces in the names
for file in ABS*; do
    newfile="${file/foo/bar}"     # Replace foo with bar
    newfile="${newfile/baz/quux}" # Replace baz with quux (repeat as needed)
    if [[ "$file" == "$newfile" ]]; then
        echo "Not renaming $file - no change decreed."
    elif [[ -f "$newfile" ]]; then
        echo "Not renaming $file - $newfile already exists."
    else
        mv -- "$file" "$newfile"       # Make the change
    fi
done
```

Comment: Good answer.  Setting `IFS` is unnecessary, even if your files have spaces (I have tested this in Bash).  In the general case (where, unlike here, you can't guarantee a substitution), it may be worth testing `[ "x$file" = "x$newfile" ] || mv -- "$file" "$newfile"` to avoid `mv` complaining about old and new being equal if neither substitution matches (I've also protected against files beginning with `-`, which we know won't happen in this specific case).

Answer (score 2):

A suitable answer depends on how the names might vary.  You could transform the names using the shell's built-in parameter substitution if you assume constant field-widths.  That's relatively limited in scope.

More interesting would be using character classes in `sed`:

```
newname=$(echo "$oldname" | sed -e 's/^\([[:alpha:]]\+\)\([[:digit:]]\+\)_/\1-\2-/')
```

that is, after a leading alphabetic prefix, add a dash, and then after the digits ending with an underscore, change *that* to a dash.

Unlike the possible solutions using parameter substitution, this approach allows any (nonzero) length from the alphabetic prefix and digits.  So you could have this as input:

```
ABS1789_2563-01
ABS1789_2563-02
ABS1789_2563-02
ABSOLUTE1789_2563-01
ABSURD1789_2563-02
ABSOLVE1789_2563-02
PREFIX1793939389_2563-02
```

put that in a script

```
#!/bin/sh
for oldname in `cat foo4.txt`
do
newname=$(echo "$oldname" | sed -e 's/^\([[:alpha:]]\+\)\([[:digit:]]\+\)_/\1-\2-/')
echo "$oldname ->$newname"
done
```

giving this output (in a suitable loop):

```
ABS1789_2563-01 ->ABS-1789-2563-01
ABS1789_2563-02 ->ABS-1789-2563-02
ABS1789_2563-02 ->ABS-1789-2563-02
ABSOLUTE1789_2563-01 ->ABSOLUTE-1789-2563-01
ABSURD1789_2563-02 ->ABSURD-1789-2563-02
ABSOLVE1789_2563-02 ->ABSOLVE-1789-2563-02
PREFIX1793939389_2563-02 ->PREFIX-1793939389-2563-02
```

Answer (score 1):

If all starts with `ABS1789_2563-`

```
for f in ABS*; do mv "$f" ABS-1789-2563-${f:13}; done
```

---

Here

```
ABS-1789-2563-
```

is simply hard coded under the assumption all your folders starts with *ABS1789_2563-*.

```
${f:13}
```

expands to the end of parameter `$f` starting from offset 13 - often referred to as *substring*. In bash *Substring Expansion*.

See [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), section:

> ```
> ${parameter:offset}
> ${parameter:offset:length}
> ```

Comment: Kindly, what is the meaning of 13 at the end of your command. thanks a lot!

Comment: `${var:13}` evaluates to "the value of the variable `var` starting at the thirteenth character".  So if `var` were set to `qwertyuiopasdfghjkl`, `${var:13}` would be equivalent to `fghjkl`.